# Struct Notation

Tags: c, struct, boolean

I need clarification for the following notation in C:

I have a struct, and within that struct I have the following field:

`bool (* process_builtin)(struct esh_command *);`

I am pretty confused here.. So this is a boolean field.. What exactly is `process_builtin`? I already have a struct `esh_command` defined, but I have no clue where this plays in this field. Can someone please explain the whole thing's meaning?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's not a boolean field, that's a [pointer to a function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_pointer) taking a `struct esh_command*` and returning a `bool`; the field is called `process_builtin`.

You could also write:

```
typedef bool (* process_builtin_t)(struct esh_command *);
```

in which case `process_builtin_t` would be a type and in which case you could write the definition of that `struct` member as:

```
process_builtin_t process_builtin;
```

Comment: Would: `bool process_builtins(struct esh_command *command)` be a correct definition header?

Comment: You mean, can a pointer to a function with that prototype be stored in the member? Yes.

Comment: How can this "member" be refered to? `name_of_struct->process_builtin`? So `process_builtin` function stores true/false in `->process_builtin` member?

Comment: As I said in my answer, `process_builtin` is *not* a boolean; it's a function pointer that you can call. `bool foo = name_of_struct.process_builtin(some_esh_cmd);`

Comment: Oh got it. So why would it be defined as a "member of a struct"? Aren't members, typically, variables that hold & store something related to the struct?

Comment: In this case, the `struct` member holds a pointer to code instead of data. It means that each instance can have associated with it some function. That's sometimes useful.

Comment: Why would it be useful if the function can just be declared outside of the struct? How would it be different since that member will not store anything that belongs to the struct as a "property"?

Comment: The point is that different instances of the `struct` can store pointers to different functions, so the function pointer encodes an instance-specific action to perform.

Comment: How is it going to be an instance-specific action? That function would only be written once. Or can we set that pointer to point to a specific function? If so, how do I do that?

Comment: A function pointer is a pointer, so you make it point to a function. That's just a matter of, e.g., `char *(*p)(char const *, int) = strchr;` Then, you can reset `p = strrchr` if you want, because the functions have the same prototype. Look up function pointers in any good C book.

Answer (score 2):

This a pointer to [function](http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/function-pointers.html). Using [cdecl](http://cdecl.org/) (and changing `bool` to `int`) reveals:

```
declare process_builtin as pointer to function (pointer to struct esh_command) returning int
```

This [link](http://cdecl.ridiculousfish.com/?q=int+%28%2a+process_builtin%29%28struct+esh_command+%2a%29) is a permalink to the entire output.

Answer (score 1):

`process_builtin` is a function pointer. The function it points to takes a `esh_command*` as parameter and returns a `bool`.

Comment: Technically, it takes a `struct esh_command*` (not an `esh_command*`) as `esh_command` doesn't name a type in `C` without the `struct` keyword.

Answer (score 0):

That is a pointer to a function that takes a pointer to struct esh_command as an argument and returns a bool value.

http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/function-pointers.html